# How to check when was the last time anacron successfully run?

Tags: cron, anacron

How can I check when was the last time anacron completed all the daily/weekly/monthly jobs? I understand that the timestamps at /var/spool/anacron are the times anacron started, but it can be that the system was restarted or shutdown between start and completion.

Is it possible to check the status and timestamp of completion of every anacron job seperately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When cronjobs fails to run you will get an e-mail in /var/mail/user.
This e-mail will contain a line like this:

```
  Subject: Cron <root@server28> test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily ) (failed)
```

...

```
Date: Sun, 12 Feb 2012 06:25:05 +0100 (CET)

/etc/cron.daily/logrotate: error: error running non-shared postrotate script for /var/log/fail2ban.log of '/var/log/fail2ban.log ' run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/logrotate exited with return code 1
```

You can  see the time and which cronjob failed to run.